# Let's make MVC, Singletons, and data sharing across multiple view controllers clear for beginners

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, singleton

*Being able to share data between multiple view controllers and doing that in a way that makes use of recommended patterns such as MVC seems to be essential to create good apps, but my problem is that these things aren't clear at all for me.* 
**I am conscient that this question is really dense, but for things to be clear I think you really need to understand the whole thing.**

First of all we need to be sure of what Model, View and Controller are doing, here is how I would describe them, **please tell me if I'm right about that**:

- **Model** : a class that's responsible for managing data, and only that *(for example, a class that will go on the web to retrieve information, such as weather forecast)*.
- **View** : a view is an object that's displayed to the user, who can often interact with it, that's the objects that you can drag and drop in Interface Builder *(for example a button)* and you might also create one from scratch, or custom an already existing one by subclassing it.
- **Controller** : a controller is responsible for managing a view and its subviews, it receives events (such as viewDidLoad, or even when the user taps a button) and can react to it, for example, it might change the text of a label.

Now about the way they are interacting between each other, I'd say that the controller is *between* the view and the model, it's managing the view and might ask for data to the model. In addition to receiving events from the view, it might also receive events from the model, for example, if the controller asks to the model for a specific data on the web (let's say if it asks weather for a specific city) the data won't be available immediately, instead, the model will notify the controller so that it can update the view with the data it received. **Am I right?**

One of the first thing **I'm wondering** is **if an object could be considered as a model if it isn't here to retrieve data, but to do other things that are simply not related to the view**, for example, could an object that's responsible for communicating and managing a bluetooth accessory considered as a model ? Could an object that sends data to a cloud considered as a model ? And what about a Tic Tac Toe AI ?

Then, singleton instances, I often heard of them when an app had to share data between multiple views, **but first of all, I never really understood why it was necessary to use them in this case ?**

Then, here is a singleton that I found in [an article of the We Heart Swift website](http://www.weheartswift.com/object-oriented-programming-swift/).

```
class Singleton {
    struct Static {
        static let instance = Singleton()
    }

    class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
        return Static.instance
    }
}

Singleton.sharedInstance
```

The problem if that I have had difficulties to find anywhere more details about why it's written in this way, and **most of all, can a singleton have an initializer that takes arguments? How to add properties and methods to a singleton like this one? What are exactly the `Static` structure and the `sharedInstance`?**

My last question is about why, technically, does a singleton makes it possible to get an access to things we have defined somewhere else? What I mean is that if I create an instance of let's say, a `Dog` class in my AppDelegate, and if I want to access to this specific instance in a view controller, then it wouldn't be possible, so how does singleton makes that possible under the hood?

EDIT : Oh, and, is the use of singletons recommended by Apple?

Thank you.

Comment: Too long, too many questions, too many topics.  Try narrowing your focus to a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the `static` in the struct. Static is essentially a class variable that persists for every instance of that class, so when you make the shared instance static, every time you access it, even from another instance of `Singleton.instance` it is the same variable because it is static. It persists amongst instances. However, Swift does not support class variables yet, so when it does, that should quickly replace the Struct syntax that is common of singletons. It is very similar to static variables in java.

For example:

```
class Singleton { 
    var someVar = 0 


    struct Static { 
        static let instance = Singleton() 
    } 
}
```

to create a singleton with a variable and the following to access it:

```
let foo = Singleton.Static.instance 
foo.someVar = 11 

let bar = Singleton.Static.instance 
println(bar.someVar) // Prints 11
```

As you can see, `bar.someVar` was never set, and that is because the variable for the shared instance was set, so it prints 11.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand `static` is a way to tell the we will access to the same instance of the class as the first and only one that was initialized, whether it was?

Comment: static is essentially a super controller of a class. Every instance of that class points to the same static variables.

Comment: Ok, but then, let's say that I want to add a property to a singleton, do I add it as I would do for any class ? Or must I do something else ?

Comment: Same question for methods, and also, is the initialization of a singleton always empty or can it take multiple arguments, as any class would?

Comment: I must say that the notion of singleton and static is still not that much clear to me :/

Comment: You access that class's singleton struct and set the static property

Comment: `let someInstance = Singleton().Static.instance`  to access the singleton. `someInstance.someVar = someValue` to set that instance's variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68933/discussion-between-trevor-anne-denise-and-bluehound).